# Await HttpClient.PostAsync() timing out. Have I missed something?

Tags: c#, python, asp.net-core

I have two Web APIs, one made in .NET Core and another in Python using Flask. I am trying to make the .NET Core API to POST to an endpoint in the Python-Flask API and get a response message in return.

I am using System.Net.Http but when it gets to the Await HttpClient.PostAsync() it hangs indefinitely and ultimately timeout. What's even more strange is that sometimes it works perfectly fine, connects and gets the response almost immediately with no problems.

I attempted to debug the Python-Flask API to try and find if/where it gets stuck but it seems that it never actually reaches the Python-Flask API, it just sends a request and waits indefinitely.

This is the code in the .NET Core API:

```
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
        var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"key", key}
        };

        var keyContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/")};
        responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("token", keyContent);
```

This is sending a key to the /token endpoint and awaits a response.

If necessary I will add the Python-Flask API code as well. In this case it would receive the key the .NET Core API sent, verify it and send back a token but as it never reaches it (and it successfully responds when it does reach it) I feel it isn't necessary as of yet.

Am I missing something here? The fact that it works fine sometimes is what bugs me.

Comment: Code you posted here is completely fine, however I think problem is somewhere on upper level and you facing deadlock. Here is good article describing this issue: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Uriil Thank you very much for your quick reply. That article is excellent thank you. Turns out I had to add .ConfigureAwait(false) to my top level function call which has solved my problem.